# What's the difference between @pyqtSignature() and @pyqtSlot() pyqt decorators

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, signals-slots

I was trying to write a slot that connects to different pyqt signals. What I still can't wrap my head around is the difference between the two decorators @pyqtSignature() and @pyqtSlot().

Example to connect to pyqt clicked signal of QPushButton which is inherited from QAbstractButton, I used the following syntax `on_widgetName_signalName`, when using @pyqtSignature(""):

```
@pyqtSignature("")
def on_bn_gpx_select_file_clicked(self):  
    """
    Run when QPushButton is pressed, or do something
    """
    pass
```

Now when using @pyqtSlot()

```
@pyqtSlot()
def on_bn_gpx_select_file_clicked(self):  
    """
    Run when QPushButton is pressed, or do something
    """
    pass
```

My question is, what is the difference between the two decorators and when should I use @pyqtSignature or @pyqtSlot()

Thanks

Comment: Well, the documentation says that @pyqtSignal() is deprecated. Use @pyqtSlot() and forget about the other one. (If you ask me, @pyqtSlot() should really be named as @pyQtSlot() as that would be consistent with the naming scheme of PyQt.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `pyqtSignature` decorator is part of the [old-style signal and slot syntax](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/old_style_signals_slots.html), which was replaced by the [new-style signal and slot syntax](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) in PyQt-4.5.

Both decorators serve the same purpose, which is to explicitly mark a python method as a Qt slot and specify a C++ signature for it (most commonly in order to select a particular overload).  The only relevant difference between the two decorators is that `pyqtSlot` has a much more pythonic API.

There should never be any need to use `pyqtSignature` in new code - it is only really needed for backwards-compatibility.